# Ways of speeding up a MySQL FUNCTION call?

Tags: mysql

It seems that calling a `FUNCTION` in a MySQL query is utterly slow, so what ways do we have to fasten this up?

Are there "inline" functions like C/C++ has (= is there a `MERGE` algorithm not for `VIEW` but for `FUNCTION`)?

Are there other ways to fasten the `FUNCTION` *call* itself (ie: in showcase, it's hard to fasten the function itself, and the slowness comes from its calling, not its content)?

---

**Showcase**

I make a table of integers (~500k) and I do a `SELECT` on it using a `WHERE` clause. This runs in about 1 second. Then, I do the same `SELECT` but putting the `WHERE` calculus in a `FUNCTION` and execution time blows up by more than a factor 10 (about 30 seconds).

Is there a way to still use the `FUNCTION` (because in practice, I do the same calculus in the `WHERE` but on different columns, so it's like having a `WHERE x blabla AND y blabla AND z blabla...` so I want to merge all the `blabla` into one function) without blowing up the execution time?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `integers` (
    `n` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`n`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
TRUNCATE TABLE integers;
INSERT INTO integers (n) VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(5);
INSERT IGNORE INTO integers (n) (
    SELECT x.n+5*(y.n+5*(z.n))
    FROM integers AS x
    INNER JOIN integers as y
    INNER JOIN integers as z
);
INSERT IGNORE INTO integers (n) (
    SELECT x.n+95*(y.n+95*(z.n))
    FROM integers AS x
    INNER JOIN integers as y
    INNER JOIN integers as z
    WHERE y.n > 0 OR z.n > 0
);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM integers;
-- Shows it has about 568k rows

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test_speed`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `test_speed`(
    `n` INT UNSIGNED
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    RETURN (n % 128 = 0);

END$$

DELIMITER ;

SET @timer := UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

SELECT *, (i.n+1e6*j.n)
FROM integers AS i
INNER JOIN integers AS j ON j.n < 32
WHERE (i.n+1e6*j.n) % 128 = 0
;
-- Takes like 1 second

SET @d1 := UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - @timer;

SET @timer := UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

SELECT *, (i.n+1e6*j.n)
FROM integers AS i
INNER JOIN integers AS j ON j.n < 32
WHERE test_speed(i.n+1e6*j.n)
;
-- Takes like 30 seconds

SET @d2 := UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - @timer;

SELECT @d1, @d2;
-- Shows the durations
```

Note that both queries have the exact same `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      j       \N          range   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4   \N  23      100.00      Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE      i       \N          index   \N              PRIMARY 4   \N  568625  100.00      Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

But 2nd with `FUNCTION` calls is way utterly slow...

Comment: Please provide the querys you are using with the EXPLAIN Output... i think the function call isn't using anny index

Comment: Hum... I didn't thought about a version issue, because the 5.7.16 I use here does have a huge execution time gap between the two queries. The `EXPLAIN` I added shows the same output for both queries (hence I added it only one time)

Comment: indeed i wasnt a version issue that why ive remove the comment forgotten SQLYOG has a default limit off 1000 records.. looked liked both qeuries executed in the same speed